# UE4 project link error with empty description

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, unreal-engine4

I am moving bunch of c++ code from older project to UE4 project. I get link error LNK2001 or LNK1120 with empty description, which makes it very difficult to locate the problem.

I am using VS2017 community 15.9.21, with UE4 4.23 and building config development editor targeted win64.
I have other c++ projects, on which vs2017 can correctly report details of link error, so I suspect it is caused by unreal tool chain.

Any thought?

Build log:

```
14>Using Visual Studio 2017 14.16.27023 toolchain (d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023) and Windows 10.0.16299.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
14>Building 3 actions with 8 processes...
14>  [1/3] UE4Editor-Network.dll
?14>LINK : fatal error LNK1104:
14>  [2/3] UE4Editor-Protocol.dll
14>LINK : error LNK2001:
14>E:\work\QSGame_Branch\Branch_64bit_publish\QSGame 4.23\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Protocol.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the prolelm, so I post my solution here in case anyone come cross the same problem.

Any langauge pack except for english must be uninstalled. That's it.
Use visual studio installer to install/uninstall thoese language packs, if only english is installed, the problem is gone.